# Unable to correlate string using regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

After executing script, Below is my requested  data.

```
lm=eyJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYXVkIjoiMDBEM0MwMDAwMDAxQThGIiwia2lkIjoie1widFwiOlwiMDBEM0MwMDAwMDAxQThGXCIsXCJ2XCI6XCIwMkc2MTAwMDAwMEQ5d25cIixcImFcIjpcImNvbnRlbnRkb29ydXNlcnRyYW5zaWVudGtleWVuY3J5cHRcIixcInVcIjpcIjAwNTNDMDAwMDAxQ2xaU1wifSIsImNyaXQiOlsiaWF0Il0sImlhdCI6MTU0NzQ2MzUzMTE4NSwiZXhwIjowfQ%3D%3D..zc74kEU7STBxj2I0.buy73i-DeU8lWNlVrUgSAA%3D%3D.VNcpQp0XPW1wdVLCxZoSlQ%3D%3D
```

In Response Data getting below details.

```
lm%3DeyJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYXVkIjoiMDBEM0MwMDAwMDAxQThGIiwia2lkIjoie1widFwiOlwiMDBEM0MwMDAwMDAxQThGXCIsXCJ2XCI6XCIwMkc2MTAwMDAwMEQ5d25cIixcImFcIjpcImNvbnRlbnRkb29ydXNlcnRyYW5zaWVudGtleWVuY3J5cHRcIixcInVcIjpcIjAwNTNDMDAwMDAxQ2xaU1wifSIsImNyaXQiOlsiaWF0Il0sImlhdCI6MTU0NzQ2MzUzMTE4NSwiZXhwIjowfQ%253D%253D..zc74kEU7STBxj2I0.buy73i-DeU8lWNlVrUgSAA%253D%253D.VNcpQp0XPW1wdVLCxZoSlQ%253D%253D');
```

so please let me know, how I can correlate "lm" field using regular expression

Comment: Are you trying to get "lm" value from response in your second part of the question and use it in the request?

Comment: In Response,Below data is getting displayed, so pls let me know the regular expression for below data .
 
 lm%3DeyJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYXVkIjoiMDBEcTAwMDAwMDBERk1iIiwia2lkIjoie1widFwiOlwiMDBEcTAwMDAwMDBERk1iXCIsXCJ2XCI6XCIwMkc2MTAwMDAwMEQ5d25cIixcImFcIjpcImNvbnRlbnRkb29ydXNlcnRyYW5zaWVudGtleWVuY3J5cHRcIixcInVcIjpcIjAwNXEwMDAwMDA0am1LYVwifSIsImNyaXQiOlsiaWF0Il0sImlhdCI6MTU0ODUyMDY2MzU4MCwiZXhwIjowfQ%253D%253D..GfgxgBV5zACTem9S.3I-Gks6fEJwXJAT_2s3NxA%253D%253D.-UBHpwW5wpUbWYKqklFZKA%253D%253D');